# Drupal 6: Having a menu where more than one Item is active

Tags: routes

I'm trying to build a menu where a node can be a child of more than one item. That's not really an issue because Drupal 6 can handle it. However only one parent menu item will be active.

It's some sort of a portfolio where a client-node can be a child of photography and design and when the page of the node is opened the entry for photography and for design should be active.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Drupal has built in the assumption that only only one item in a single menu can be active.

You hack the core menu system or create your own, but both would not be recommended.

The best workaround I can think of, is to expend the menu and use css and JavaSript to show/hide the menus and mark them as active. This could be doable but might be quite hard if you have a complex menu structure.